# iTunes:How to update the binary and upload into Appstore?

Tags: iphone

I have an application in Appstore. I have fixed few issues and want to update again in Appstore. How to remove the existing app present in Appstore and update with the version what i have? I went and saw in iTunes connect, there is one button called "Add version". I don't want to add any new version for my previous app, i just to want overwride the binary with the latest one. 
Anyone please hint me on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing an approved binary, you are creating a new version of that binary, e.g., v1.0.0 vs v1.0.1.  You need to maintain this distinction because that is what is used by the application store to determine whether or not an application needs to be updated on a particular device.  Another benefit of the versioning is that it allows your current version to remain available to the public until the updated version is approved by Apple.  Along with the new version, you can decide to change the meta-data associated with the application (keywords, etc..), which is not something you can do without creating a new version.

Once Apple approves the new version, your previous binary will no longer be available to the consumer, only your latest version will visible in the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a version is exactly what you want to do.  In doing so you will be overriding the version available to users of the App Store.  Once you have added the new binary and it has been approved, upon release it will be the **only** version of the application available via iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

An added version submitted to iTunes Connect will override/overwrite the current version after Apple approves the new version and you release it to the App store.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, there's no way than deploying another version. Any app-modification results in a new version. 
But, ... what's the problem with that? Users who have already installed your app will have noticed some bugs and they will appreciate you fixed them. 
Go for "Add Version"! Fortunatelly you won't have to commmit any information than the binary itself, beside some notices on differences from the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new version.  This will allow any existing users to upgrade to the new version, while new users will automatically get the newest version.  Once the new version is approved and released to the App Store, it will become the "current" version.